# how to resolve NoClassDefFoundError?

Tags: java, spring, gradle

I am having the class UriComponentsContributor in my classpath. But in run time it throwing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception

I added spring-hateoas 0.1.0.RELEASE dependency in my build.gradle file and i am having all required dependencies.

```
dependencies{
compile group: 'org.springframework.hateoas', name: 'spring-hateoas', version: '0.1.0.RELEASE'
}
```

I am expecting that spring boot application should run without run time exceptions

This is the exception I'm seeing:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/hateoas/mvc/UriComponentsContributor

Comment: When asking about errors, exceptions etc. please post the entire stacktrace or message you get. That might contain some relevant information you missed but which helps us help you.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/hateoas/mvc/UriComponentsContributor

Comment: Did you run a gradle build ?

Comment: Please add that information to your question via an [edit]. That let's you format it nicely if you have more data - if you'd post the console output and how you call gradle (and probably some additional config) that would help.

Comment: You're using mixed dependencies. In particular, that version of Spring HATEOAS is about 5 years out of date.

Comment: Yes i refreshed my gradle file still it showing the same error. while running the application.java file. @AK47

Comment: will i try newer version of spring hateoas @chrylis